# Oracle to_char format number with fill mode (FM0000)

Tags: sql, oracle

I use the `TO_CHAR` function to format number from `0001` to `9999`, and to fit the column size (`VARCHAR2(4)`) where the value is inserted (even if value is > 9999).

I use the function like this:

```
TO_CHAR(n, 'FM0000')
```

Examples that work:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(1, 'FM0000') FROM DUAL;
```

*Result*: `0001`

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(1234, 'FM0000') FROM DUAL;
```

*Result*: `1234`

But when I test **with a value greater than 9999, I get an extra character**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(12345, 'FM0000') FROM DUAL;
```

*Result*: `#####`

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(123456, 'FM0000') FROM DUAL;
```

*Result*: `#####`

*For information, the result I expected was `####` (on 4 chars).*

To sum up:

- When the value to convert corresponds to the expected size (4), the converted value has the same length (4)
- When the value to convert is longer than the expected size (5 or more), the converted value has one more character than the expected length (5).

**How to explain this ?**

I didn't found explanation in the Oracle documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i170559

I tried on several Oracle version (9, 10, 11) and the result is the same.

**The workaround** I found is to truncate the result with RPAD() function `RPAD(TO_CHAR(n,'FM0000'), 4)` but I need to understand why the TO_CHAR function is not enough.

Comment: `SELECT TO_CHAR(-1, 'FM0000') FROM DUAL;`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What value do you want returned if you select a number greater than 9999 (say 12345)?

Comment: If you run your query with <=4 digits in SQL\*Plus, you'll notice the column header always appears with five characters, `TO_CH`. It still has to allow for the sign of the value, in addition to the four significant digits you want. (As Florin's query shows...). You could also try with `'FMS000'` to see it explicitly for positive values. You could use `substr(to_char(...), -4)` as an alternative workaround.

Comment: @Ollie the value is saved into two columns, one in VARCHAR2(4) (old system compatibility), and the other in NUMBER (new system). The idea is to keep the old system working for values between 1 and 9999 (no negative values), the new system allows values greater than 9999. In the VARCHAR(4) column, the value shall have the format 0000, so a value like 12345 may be saved as '####' (in this case it will be handled by the new system).

Comment: @AlexPoole `select length(TO_CHAR(1234, 'FM0000')) from dual` returns `4`, the `FM0000` is supposed to remove the 'minus sign' (if value is positive of course). I tried `FMS0000`, it always contains `+` sign, it could be a solution, I just need to remove it to fit in the column.

Comment: @kev - the length of the formatted string is four characters, but it's implicitly `varchar2(5)` to *allow* for the sign. `TO_CHAR()` doesn't know it can't be negative, even with `FM`.

Comment: @AlexPoole In this case why the formatted length for 1234 is not 5 ? There is no space for the +/- sign.

Comment: Because FM removed the leading space. `LENGTH(TO_CHAR(1234, '0000'))` is 5.

Comment: I understand now, `TO_CHAR(12345, '0000')` already returns `#####` so the `FM` will do nothing in this case as there is no leading space.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your format model still has to allow for the sign of the value. There is no way to indicate to `TO_CHAR()` that it can never be negative (if that is in fact the case for your values). Even with a 4-digit number the formatting allows allows for five characters, as you can see from the column heading:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(1234, 'FM0000') FROM DUAL;

TO_CH
-----
1234
```

Notice the column heading is `TO_CH`, which is five characters, not four. If you have a negative number (as Florin suggested) you need that extra space:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(-1234, 'FM0000') FROM DUAL;

TO_CH
-----
-1234
```

Without the `FM` modifier you get a leading space in the returned string for positive values, so `LENGTH(TO_CHAR(1234, '0000'))` is 5 but `LENGTH(TO_CHAR(1234, 'FM0000'))` is 4, because the leading space (which normally makes the values in the column right-justified) is suppressed. With a negative value the length of the returned string is 5 either way. The format model determines that the returned data type is `varchar2(5)` to *allow* for the sign, even if you know there will never be negative values - there isn't any way for the format model to reflect that.

You can see it with positive values too if you force the sign to be shown:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(1234, 'FMS0000') FROM DUAL;

TO_CH
-----
+1234
```

There isn't anything you can do about that in the `TO_CHAR` call. As an alternative to your `RPAD` workaround, you could use `SUBSTR` to only get the last four characters of the formatted string:

```
SQL> SELECT SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(12345, 'FM0000'), -4) FROM DUAL

SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(1
----------------
####
```

But if you do have negative values you'd lose the sign:

```
SQL> SELECT SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(-1234, 'FM0000'), -4) FROM DUAL

SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(-
----------------
1234
```

With your RPAD you keep the sign but lose the fourth significant digit:

```
SQL> SELECT RPAD(TO_CHAR(-1234, 'FM0000'), 4) FROM DUAL

RPAD(TO_CHAR(-12
----------------
-123
```

which also isn't good. You may not have to deal with negative numbers; but if you're dealing with number larger than you expect (i.e. you get a number >= 10000 when you're expecting only <= 9999) then I'm not sure you can be certain you won't see an (invalid?) negative number at some point too. This seems to be a data problem rather than a formatting problem, on some level anyway.

---

Based on your comment to Ollie, another approach which might be more explicit and obvious to future maintainers of the code is to spell it out in a CASE:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN n BETWEEN 0 AND 9999 THEN TO_CHAR(n, 'FM0000') ELSE '####' END FROM DUAL
```

Which would also allow you to leave the string column null or use some other magic value rather than `####`, if you wanted to.

And another way to trim the value, which *may* also be clearer, is with CAST:

```
SQL> SELECT CAST(TO_CHAR(12345, 'FM0000') AS VARCHAR2(4)) FROM DUAL;

CAST
----
####
```