# Insert data to a particular column using a variable

Tags: oracle11g

Is it possible to insert data to a particular column using a variable? When I execute the below code, it runs indefinitely.

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
maxi number(5);
begin
select max(salary) into maxi from employees;
insert into employees
values
(207,'Soumya','Ghosh','sghosh87','245.322.4322','22-FEB-16','MK_MAN',maxi,NULL,100,20);
dbms_output.put_line('Value of maximum salary is :' ||maxi);
end;
```

Comment: If it runs indefinitely then the insert is probably just blocked. Do you have  uncommitted changes to that table in another session/client?

Comment: Hi @Alex Poole.. Actually, the data type for variable 'maxi' is 'number'. Is the insert statement not running due to mismatch of data type?Is it that system was expecting a numeric value instead of a numeric variable for the column 'salary' of 'employees' table? I mean, I wanted to check if a numerical value can be inserted via a variable of data type 'number'. Is it possible? Can you please answer my question?

Comment: Of course it's possible to insert data to a column using a variable. If implicit conversion was necessary it would either work almost instantly or give you an error; it wouldn't run indefinitely. A likely scenario is that you also tried to insert into that table from another session and didn't commit or roll back, leaving the table locked (e.g. because of a unique/primary key causing it to wait). But how are you executing the code? You haven't shown a trailing slah `/` on a line on its own, so in some clients nothing would actually execute. You *might* see nothing happening and think it is...

Comment: Hi Alex..I run the code now. It is working successfully. Thank you for your explanation. You were correct that I tried to insert into table from another session and didn't commit/roll back. This was holding back the code execution.

Comment: Alex, one more query I have. I tried asking it as a question but I got an error saying 'it does not meet the standards' something like that.

Comment: select substr(4590876,2,3) from dual;--590
select to_number(substr(to_char(4590876,'9999999'),2,3)) from dual;--459... Why do they give different answers? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Because by default `to_char()` leaves a leading space to allow for a - sign if the number being converted is negative. [See this answer for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32735449/266304), and how to use the FM modifier...

Comment: Alex. thank you so much for your explanation. Your help is very much appreciated.