# How to convert decimal to duration

Tags: sql, plsql

My data is in decimal type eg. 1.5. I need to convert into DD: HH:MM.

So in my case it should display as 1 Hr and 30 min. I'm new to sql & plsql.

Answer (score 0):

so you have a numeric value and you want to covert it to the string format days hours and minutes?  -- Here are the formulas for the various parts if the variable or column is named myhours

```
 days = floor(myhours / 24)

 hours = floor(myhours mod 24)

 mins = 60 * ((myhour mod 24) - floor(myhour mod 24))
```

Then you would need to cast each of those to a varchar (with 0 prefix)

```
 days =  RIGHT('00' + CAST(floor(myhours / 24) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) 

 hours = RIGHT('00' + CAST(floor(myhours mod 24) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)

 mins = RIGHT('00' + CAST(60 * ((myhour mod 24) - floor(myhour mod 24)) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```

and concatenate them together.

```
 RIGHT('00' + CAST(floor(myhours / 24) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':' +
 RIGHT('00' + CAST(floor(myhours mod 24) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':' +
 RIGHT('00' + CAST(60 * ((myhour mod 24) - floor(myhour mod 24)) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like here: where **dec_hours** is the time in **decimal hours** and return format is *dd hh24:mi:ss*

```sql
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(  TO_CHAR(TRUNC(dec_hours * 3600 / 86400),'FM00') || ' ' ||
              TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD((dec_hours * 3600), 86400) / 3600),'FM00') || ':' ||
              TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD((dec_hours * 3600), 3600) / 60), 'FM00') || ':' ||
              TO_CHAR(MOD((dec_hours * 3600), 60), 'FM00') 
          ) "DD_HH24_MI_SS"
FROM DUAL
--  
--  Result for 25.52 is
--  DD_HH24_MI_SS 
--  ---------------
--  01 01:31:12 
--
-- for 1.5      *** 00 01:30:00
-- for 734.225  *** 30 14:13:30
--
```

If you don't need seconds just exclude the last concatenation:

```sql
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(  TO_CHAR(TRUNC(1.52 * 3600 / 86400),'FM00') || ' ' ||
              TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD((1.52 * 3600), 86400) / 3600),'FM00') || ':' ||
              TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD((1.52 * 3600), 3600) / 60), 'FM00') --|| ':' ||
            --  TO_CHAR(MOD((1.52 * 3600), 60), 'FM00') 
          ) "DD_HH24_MI"
FROM DUAL
--
--  R e  s u l t :
--  DD_HH24_MI 
--  ---------------
--  00 01:31
```

Regards...

Comment: Thank you.. It works. Please advice what is FM00.. And other case i have is

Comment: @KannanJ You're wellcome. Format 'FM00' means that output will show 2 number characters (with leading zeros if result is shorter). Result 1 will be 01. If it was 'FM90' there would be just 1 without leading zero character. See accepted answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734607/oracle-to-char-format-number-with-fill-mode-fm0000 . Glad to help. Regards...

Comment: @KannanJ You may need to format fill mode of days (first one) to 'FM000' or 'FM990' or even more if there is a possibility to have more then 99 days as a result.